# Svg image filter for IE10 responsive issues

Tags: svg, responsive

a fallback strategy for **CSS filter** in IE10 and up. It was harder than I thought but in the end, I found and edited this peace of code which in the end actually works. Feel free to use it since most of the codes don't work unless you use plugins. My issue now is making this image responsive for overall usage. I work for a company and they need to have a solid code that could be **reused** in the future. The biggest issue is how to fit the SVG and image, without having this extra space around it. It should be with setting the sizes of the elements, but I can't figure out how should I set them...
If you open inspect e. you will see it. Now is there any universal way of creating code suitable for any image without making this space?

```
<h1>
    Test
</h1>
<h3>...</h3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 500 477" width="500" height="477">
    <defs>
        <filter id="filtersPicture">
            <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1"
                k3="0" k4="0" />
            <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image id="one" filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="477" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href="2.jpg" />
</svg>
   html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }

    img.grayscale {
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+ */
        filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */

    }
    #svgroot {
       

        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block; /* They are inline blocks, it's just here to prevent them from wrapping */
    }
```

*It's easier to see it here. When *
https://codepen.io/lukagurovic/pen/JwBLYw

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you forget to post the code?

Comment: Yes, but its here! Thank you for the notice